# coc.nvim having issues with background color and error messages

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc

[image: Background color issue]

Above is what I see in NeoVim 0.4.4 (on Ubuntu) when I get a type error using coc.nvim and the Haskell Language Server. My configuration for all background and theme related things are:

```
    syntax on
    set t_Co=256
" Enable italics
    set t_ZH=^[[3m
    set t_ZR=^[[23m
    
" Initialize colorscheme
    highlight Normal ctermbg=NONE
    let g:lightline = {
          \ 'colorscheme': 'nord',
          \ }
    set noshowmode " nvim no longer shows the mode we're in; that's shown by lightline
    let g:nord_cursor_line_number_background = 1
    let g:nord_italic = 1
    let g:nord_italic_comments = 1
    let g:nord_underline = 1
    let g:nord_bold = 1
    "let g:gruvbox_itaic = 1

    colorscheme nord
    hi! clear Conceal
```

I do not know what could be causing the error, and as far as I remember, this was never an issue until recently. I have not tweaked my config in the time that has lapsed before this error appeared and after. I am also using tmux as well, but the error persists whether I open NeoVim in tmux or not. How should I go about solving this problem, and are there any places I could look to learn more about resolving such issues like this in the future?

Comment: You should check out [this answer related to debugging your .vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file), you may find it helpful.